# How to get selected properties of a child node under a node?

Tags: json, aem, jcr, sling

i am new in adobe cq5 .I created a page test in my repository inside the 
content node of page.I have 100 nodes example test-1 , test-2,test-3....test-100.I want to retrieve the selected properties of these nodes like name , modification date etc.How can i achieve this ? can anybody help regarding this.

Answer (score 3):

From your question title, you want to get a JSON representation of your nodes. This is a built in feature (which should be blocked on the dispatcher though):
Just add `.X.json` to your path whereas `X` is a the depth, e.g. `http://localhost:4502/content.2.json`

If you want to have XML you can just add the extenstion `.xml` to your path, though there it will just return the properties of the specified page and not the complete hierarchy as with JSON.

Answer (score 2):

If you want get data through all hierarchy use 'infinity' selector and 'json' extension.

for example

```
http://localhost:4502/content/geometrixx/en/toolbar.infinity.json
```

Comment: This does not work on folders, though. But you are right for pages, what seems to be what he wants. .-1.json does the same.

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box you can use the `parent-folder-of-your-nodes.N.json` notation as shown above.

If you need a specific format with just those properties you can write a script or servlet and mount it on a specific selector so that `parent-folder-of-your-nodes.your-selector.json` returns your custom format.

The http://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/servlets.html documentation should help with that, and there are numerous examples of such Sling servlets and scripts in the Apache Sling source code, for example under http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/sling/trunk/launchpad/